# How to watch for changes in a nested object inside a FireBase Table for web

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently if have a FireBase table that look like this:
[image]

I want to create a query that not only watches the changes inside `lists` but also changes in `items`
for now this function only watches changes in `lists`:

```
firebase.database()
  .ref('lists')
  .child('gy87bb87')
  .on('value', snap => {
     callback(snap.val()
  );
});
```

Is this possible or what do i have to change to accomplish this?

Having the loop i want to call for rendering only the first list items dynamically
`Object.values(listData[0].items).map(item => (
   <Checkbox size="big" name="checkbox" value={item.text} />
 ))`

Comment: But if you change something in an item doesn't that mean that the list is changed? So basicly aren't you already watching changes in items?

Comment: When i change for example `text` content to Lorum this change is not visible, but when i change itemCount to `2` it is visible

Comment: @RonaldZwiers Are you 100% sure the listener doesn't detect the change? Andre is right, queries in the Realtime Database are "deep", meaning the entire child tree is returned.. The listener shall return the entire object corresponding to the subtree under `gy87bb87`.

Comment: I just tested it and you guys are right the problem is looping through the items (updated the question)

Comment: @RenaudTarnec So perhaps my loop for displaying the items is wrong?

Comment: You should use the forEach() method of the DataSnapshot, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot